# Using lstlisting inside a macro fails: Text dropped after begin of listing

Tags: macros, listings

My first code example below runs fine. It does conditional compilation
based on whether `\flag` is defined or not.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\ifdefined\flag
\begin{lstlisting}
foo
\end{lstlisting}
\else
\begin{lstlisting}
bar
\end{lstlisting}
\fi

\end{document}
```

Now I try to create a macro for the conditional compilation like so.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\def\flag{}
\newcommand{\ifflag}[2]{\ifdefined\flag#1\else#2}
\begin{document}

\ifflag{
\begin{lstlisting}
foo
\end{lstlisting}
}{
\begin{lstlisting}
bar
\end{lstlisting}
}

\end{document}
```

Compiling this fails like this.

```
Package Listings Warning: Text dropped after begin of listing on input line 15.
```

What did I do wrong in the second example?

Comment: You can't have an `lstlisting` environment in the argument to another command. And even if this problem could be solved, you'd lose the end lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can offer a macro `\UDcollectverbarg` with the following syntax:

`\UDcollectverbarg{⟨^^M-replacement⟩}{⟨Mandatory 1⟩}{⟨Mandatory 2⟩}⟨verbatimized argument⟩`

which yields:

`⟨Mandatory 1⟩{⟨Mandatory 2⟩{⟨verbatimized argument⟩}}`

, with each character `^^M` that denotes an end of a line being replaced by the token-sequence `⟨^^M-replacement⟩`.

The Mandatory-arguments are mandatory. If they consist of several tokens, they must be nested into catcode-1/2-character-pair / braces.
If reading and tokenizing is necessary, this will take place under unchanged category code régime.
The verbatim-Arg is also mandatory. It is to be read and tokenized under verbatim category code régime. If its first character is a brace, it will be "assumed" that the argument is nested into braces.  Otherwise it will be assumed, that the ending of that argument is delimited by that first character—like the argument of `\verb`.
Empty-lines will not be ignored.

I chose this syntax as with this syntax you can collect verbatimized arguments within the second mandatory argument by nesting calls to `\UDcollectverbarg` within `\UDcollectverbarg`'s first mandatory argument.

E.g.,

```
\UDcollectverbarg{<^^M-replacement>}%
                 {\UDcollectverbarg{<^^M-replacement>}{\UDcollectverbarg{<^^M-replacement>}{<actionA>}}}% <- Mandatory 1
                 {<actionB>}%                     <- Mandatory 2
                 <verbatimized argument 1><verbatimized argument 2><verbatimized argument 3>
```

yields:

```
\UDcollectverbarg{<^^M-replacement>}{\UDcollectverbarg{<^^M-replacement>}{<actionA>}}% <- Mandatory 1
                 {<actionB>{<verbatimized argument 1>}}%        <- Mandatory 2
                 <verbatimized argument 2><verbatimized argument 3>
```

yields:

```
\UDcollectverbarg{<^^M-replacement>}{<actionA>}% <- Mandatory 1
                 {<actionB>{<verbatimized argument 1>}{<verbatimized argument 2>}}% <- Mandatory 2
                 <verbatimized argument 3>
```

yields:

```
<actionA>{<actionB>{<verbatimized argument 1>}{<verbatimized argument 2>}{<verbatimized argument 3>}}
```

Assume `<actionA>` = `\@firstofone`:

```
\@firstofone{<actionB>{<verbatimized argument 1>}{<verbatimized argument 2>}{<verbatimized argument 3>}}
```

yields:

```
<actionB>{<verbatimized argument 1>}{<verbatimized argument 2>}{<verbatimized argument 3>}
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

%%<-------------------- Code for \UDcollectverbarg -------------------->
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%......................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \@secondoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo{ }{}\@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%......................................................................
\begingroup
\catcode`\^^M=12 %
\@firstofone{%
  \endgroup%
  \newcommand\UDEndlreplace[2]{\romannumeral0\@UDEndlreplace{#2}#1^^M\relax{}}%
  \newcommand*\@UDEndlreplace{}%
  \long\def\@UDEndlreplace#1#2^^M#3\relax#4#5{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#3}%
    { #5{#4#2}}{\@UDEndlreplace{#1}#3\relax{#4#2#1}{#5}}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UDcollectverbarg[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\do\@makeother % <- this and the next line switch to
  \dospecials        %    verbatim-category-code-régime.
  \catcode`\{=1      % <- give opening curly brace the usual catcode so a 
                     %    curly-brace-balanced argument can be gathered in
                     %    case of the first thing of the verbatimized-argument 
                     %    being a curly opening brace.
  \catcode`\ =10     % <- give space and horizontal tab the usual catcode so \UD@collectverbarg
  \catcode`\^^I=10   %    cannot catch a space or a horizontal tab as its 4th undelimited argument.
                     %    (Its 4th undelimited argument denotes the verbatim-
                     %     syntax-delimiter in case of not gathering a
                     %     curly-brace-nested argument.)
  \kernel@ifnextchar\bgroup
  {% seems a curly-brace-nested argument is to be caught:
    \catcode`\}=2    % <- give closing curly brace the usual catcode also.
    \UD@collectverbarg{#1}{#2}{#3}{}%
  }{% seems an argument with verbatim-syntax-delimiter is to be caught:
    \do\{% <- give opening curly brace the verbatim-catcode again.
    \UD@collectverbarg{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@collectverbarg[4]{%
  \do\ %   <- Now that \UD@collectverbarg has the delimiter or
  \do\^^I%    emptiness in its 4th arg, give space and horizontal tab
         %    the verbatim-catcode again.
  \do\^^M% <- Give the carriage-return-character the verbatim-catcode.
  \long\def\@tempb##1#4{%
    %\edef\@tempb{##1}%
    \def\@tempb{##1}%
    \@onelevel@sanitize\@tempb % <- Turn characters into their "12/other"-pendants.
                               %    This may be important with things like the 
                               %    inputenc-package which may make characters 
                               %    active/which give them catcode 13(active).
    \expandafter\UDEndlreplace\expandafter{\@tempb}{#1}{\def\@tempb}% <- this starts 
                               %    the loop for replacing endline-characters.
    \expandafter\UD@@collectverbarg\expandafter{\@tempb}{#2}{#3}% <- this "spits 
                               %    out the result.
  }%
  \@tempb
}%
\newcommand\UD@@collectverbarg[3]{%
  \endgroup
  #2{#3{#1}}%
}%
%%<---------------- End of code for \UDcollectverbarg ----------------->

\usepackage{listings}

% As a usage-example let's now define a macro \ifflag which
% collects two verbatim-arguments and does spit out one of them wrapped into
% \scantokens.
% Basically \ifflag is a wrapper for calling \UDcollectverbarg and
% passing the verbatimized arguments to \@ifflag
\newcommand\ifflag{%
  \UDcollectverbarg{^^J}%
                   {\UDcollectverbarg{^^J}{\@firstofone}}%
                   {\@ifflag}%
}%
\newcommand\@ifflag[2]{%
  \ifdefined\flag\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  {\scantokens{#1}}%
  {\scantokens{#2}}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Listing when flag not defined:

\ifflag{
\begin{lstlisting}
foo1
   foo2
foo3
\end{lstlisting}
}{
\begin{lstlisting}
bar1
   bar2
bar3
\end{lstlisting}
}

\def\flag{}

Listing when flag defined:

\ifflag{
\begin{lstlisting}
foo1
   foo2
foo3
\end{lstlisting}
}{
\begin{lstlisting}
bar1
   bar2
bar3
\end{lstlisting}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to the one given by the master @Ulrich Diez. The package `scontents` allows to store content `verbatim` to be reused, I have only adapted a little the entry of your example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{scontents}
\def\flag{}
\newcommand{\ifflag}[2]{%
\ifdefined\flag #1
\fi
\unless\ifdefined\flag #2
\fi}
\begin{document}
% foo
\begin{scontents}[store-env=foo]
\begin{lstlisting}
foo
\end{lstlisting}
\end{scontents}
% baz
\begin{scontents}[store-env=baz]
\begin{lstlisting}
foo
\end{lstlisting}
\end{scontents}

\ifflag{\getstored[1]{foo}}{\getstored[1]{baz}}

\end{document}
```

Saludos